# What do the compilerOptions in VS Code jsconfig.json do?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

VS Code's documentation for the jsconfig.json file has a section on `compilerOptions`. For instance:

> `target`  Specifies which default library (lib.d.ts) to use. The values are "es3", "es5", "es6", "es2015", "es2016", "es2017", "es2018", "es2019", "es2020", "esnext".

> `module`  Specifies the module system, when generating module code. The values are "amd", "commonJS", "es2015", "es6", "esnext", "none", "system", "umd".

What is the implication of these settings? These are not used by the actual code bundling process (Webpack or similar). Why does the editor need to know these? What does it do with this information?

TS is always compiled by `tsc`, so it's obvious what purpose the compiler options serve. But not so obvious what purpose they serve in the JS context.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: Basically the same thing as the tsconfig.json options; inform the language service of what's happening so it can warn you when you do something counter to the options you've selected. Like you use Array.prototype.includes, but you've selected "es5" as the `target`. See also https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JavaScript-Language-Service-in-Visual-Studio

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, I see all the "It's like tsconfig.json but for JS", but that doesn't exactly explain it. TS is always compiled by TSC, so it's obvious what purpose the compiler options serve. But not so obvious what purpose they serve in the JS context.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks, would you like to make that an answer?

Comment: @SteveBennett You can still use tsc to check your JavaScript code. And that's exactly what your editor does.

Answer (score 1):

They're the same options as for tsconfig.json. You can find the reference documentation on all the properties in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html. [The official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_what-is-jsconfigjson) say pretty much the same thing:

> **Tip**: `jsconfig.json` is a descendant of [tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html), which is a configuration file for TypeScript. `jsconfig.json` is `tsconfig.json` with `"allowJs"` attribute set to `true`.

VS Code's builtin language support for JavaScript just comes from [the extension it uses to provide its builtin language support for TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions/typescript-language-features), which is built on tsserver and the TypeScript compiler. Not very surprising, considering that TypeScript itself already has the bits for handling JS (see the `allowJs` and `checkJs` properties).

> TS is always compiled by TSC, so it's obvious what purpose the compiler options serve. But not so obvious what purpose they serve in the JS context.

Seems pretty clear to me. Plenty of the compiler options are about when to emit warnings/errors, which VS Code will show you as problems (inline squiggly underlines, and in the Problems Panel). It's totally relevant to VS Code. For example, see the section in https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig called "Type Checking". VS Code's docs have a related section to this too: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_type-checking-javascript. VS Code also provides settings for you to do the same things as many of these if for some reason you want to do that- see all the settings whose IDs start with "`js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.`" (which is mentioned in VS Code's type-checking docs). You can find the default values of those settings in the defaultSettings.json file (which you can open by running `Preferences: Open Default Settings (JSON)` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)).